# Browserstack&Selenium - proxy configuration

Tags: selenium, proxy, browserstack

I am trying to setup the browserstack and the local testing.
I opened a tunnel using the browserstack local client like below:

```
./BrowserStackLocal.exe myCodeToken -proxyHost MY_PROXY_IP -proxyPort MY_PROXY_PORT -v -force -forcelocal
```

So it is forwardin all the trafic through my local network.
In my local /etc/hosts file I have entry like below:
127.0.0.1 dev.mysite.com

Then when I'm executing my simple selenium test the browserstack virtualmachine are able to access my domain name and everything works fine. But in some sections where I have external scripts/css/images etc. for example gooogle analitics browserstack doesn't have access to them (and to the internet as well).

The thing is that my local machine uses the MY_PROXY_IP:MY_PROXY_PORT to access the internet and it looks like the browserstack tries to forward all the trafic through my machine and it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing the `-forcelocal` parameter, as that is responsible for routing all traffic via your machine. On doing this, any public (external) css/images would be resolved directly and not via your machine.

Alternatively, if the `-forcelocal` parameter is necessary, you can try using it with `-only` parameter. In this case, the requests for domain(s) mentioned under `-only`, would be routed via your machine whereas rest of the requests would be resolved publicly.

You can execute the Local Testing binaries as follows:

`BrowserStackLocal.exe <automate-key> <the-proxy-parameters> -forcelocal -only host_name,port_no,ssl_flag`

OR

`BrowserStackLocal.exe <automate-key> <the-proxy-parameters> -forcelocal -only host1,port1,ssl_flag,host2,port2,ssl_flag` (For multiple hosts)

More details on different parameters that can be used while setting up the Local Testing connection available here - https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing#modifiers